# Python Pandas CSV remove all strings from certain column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file and I am trying to remove all strings leaving just numbers: `ex 1004.242`, in a column.  Here is my code:

```
def grabkey_env():
    df = pandas.read_csv('/Users/eeamesX/PycharmProjects/CsvTask/FIT_TC_Resolved_JIRA2.csv', usecols=(1,10),skiprows=(0,1,2,3))
    df.columns = ['keys', 'env']


    df['env'].replace(to_replace='[^0-9]+', value=' ',regex=True)


    print df

    df.to_csv('newcsv3.csv')
```

I am not getting any errors, but the regex is also not working.  Its this line ive been trying to figure out.

```
 df['env'].replace(to_replace='[^0-9]+', value=' ',regex=True)
```

Comment: Try `df['env'].str.replace('[^0-9]+', ' ')`

Comment: still doesnt change the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) `r'[^0-9.]+'` as `EdChum` suggested - only try add fullstop `.` and maybe help `r` and output get to original `df['env']` (maybe you forget it):

```
print df['env']
0            ex 1004.242
1    ex erewrwn 1004.242
2          wqwe 1004.242
Name: env, dtype: object

df['env'] = df['env'].str.replace(r'[^0-9.]+', '')
print df['env']
0    1004.242
1    1004.242
2    1004.242
Name: env, dtype: object
```

Or maybe you can use:

```
df['env'] = df['env'].str.replace(r'[^\d*\.?\d+]', '')
print df['env']
0    1004.242
1    1004.242
2    1004.242
Name: env, dtype: object
```

Comment: It prints correctly, but doesnt save to csv the way it prints?

Comment: Interesting - Do you check `df['env'] = df['env'].str.replace(r'[^\d*\.?\d+]', '')` and  `print df`